# Error Laravel 5.6, Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException"

Tags: web, laravel-5, controller, routes, bootstrap-modal

I have adjust controller name with route and send form that post method but it didnt work, i send it from modal

I have add {{ method_field('patch') }} but it still didnt work

This is from **view** :

```
<form action="{{route('edit kode', 'test')}}" method="post">
                {{ method_field('patch') }}
                {{ csrf_field() }}

                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
                    </button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="bmd-label-floating">Kode</label>
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="modalidkode">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalkode" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="bmd-label-floating">Nama Kode</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="modalnamakode" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"
                            style="margin-right: 10px">Batal
                    </button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Simpan Perubahan</button>
                </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function editCode(Request $request){
    dd($request->all());
    $edCode="05.01";
    return redirect()->back()->withSuccess($edCode. " changed");
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('/pengaturan/edit', 'AllCodeController@editCode')->name('edit kode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're expecting the request to be a `POST` request in your routes, but your form is submitting a `PATCH` request (because of the `method_field('patch')` at the top of your form). Either remove the `method_field()` call, or change `Route::post(...)` to `Route::patch(...)`.

You can read more about form method spoofing in [the Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#form-method-spoofing):

> HTML forms do not support `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` actions. So, when defining `PUT`, `PATCH` or `DELETE` routes that are called from an HTML form, you will need to add a hidden `_method` field to the form. The value sent with the `_method` field will be used as the HTTP request method:

```
<form action="/foo/bar" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</form>
```